# Refactor nested if statement

Tags: php, oop, refactoring, state-pattern

Here is simplified version of one method i have.
Still look very complex
How would one refactor this insanity?

```
protected function isTextValid()
{
    if( $this->data['allow_num'] ){
        if( $this->data['allow_space'] ){
            if( preg_match( '#^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]$#', $this->val ) ){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                $this->messages = foo ? foo : bar;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if( preg_match( '#^[a-zA-Z0-9]$#', $this->val ) ){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                $this->messages = foo? foor : bar;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if( $this->data['allow_space'] ){
            if( preg_match( '#^[a-zA-Z\s]$#', $this->val ) ){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                $this->messages = foo ? foor : bar;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if( preg_match( '#^[a-zA-Z]$#', $this->val  ) ){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                $this->messages =  foo ? foo: bar;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try refactor it using state pattern but up to no avail since im not quite familiar with the pattern.
This is what i done but quickyly abondon it.

```
interface ValidatorState{
  public function isValid();
}

class AllowNumberAndSpace implement ValidatorState{
   protected $context;
   public function __construct(Context $context){$this->context = $context}

    public function isValid(){
       if( preg_match( .. ) ){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $this->messages = foo ? foo : bar;
            return false;
        }
      $this->context->setState(OtherState);
    }
}

Class Context{
    protected $state;
    protected $allow_num_space_state;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->allow_num_space_state = new AllowNumberAndSpace($this);
       $this->state = $this->allow_num_space_state;
    }

   public function isValid(){
       return $this->state->isValid();
   }

  public function setState($state){$this->state = $state}
}
```

Obviously this only test first `if` branch, how can i automatically check other branch too?
Im quite sure there is something wrong with my approach.
Is there a way to fix this state pattern to test for all `if` branch?

**Edited**
What this method does is, it check whether `$this->value` contain expected value based on configuration attribute stored in `$this->data`

Example `$this->data = array('allow_num'=>true)`, if `$this->value='a1'` it is consider valid
Example `$this->data = array('allow_num'=>false)`, if `$this->value='a1'` it is consider invalid

Is there a way to simplified this method?

Comment: It looks like many of the elses contain the same code. Is that actually the case?

Comment: @GolezTrol i can say almost the same, but the pattern inside `preg_match` is different based on the if test

Comment: Don't overcomplicate your life with patterns just because they are in right now and people think they should apply to everything and the kitchen sink. If you just have 14 branches... it's nothing. If there are more, you need to show more explicit code. Maybe you'll get design improvement suggestions. `if/else` are faster than object instantiations and interfaces...

Comment: Agree with @CodeAngry. Nothing inherently wrong with some nested if's. It's very readable by future programmers, and not so messy that it needs to be pulled apart/overcomplicated into functions.

Comment: @CodeAngry i know that, but the method basically unreadable, i just want to make it more readable

Comment: @Slier That's why we write functions as developers. We make them work and forget about them. So make them ugly, no one will care as long as they work. People will just call the function, not analyze and become mesmerized with your code. Worry about code aspect if it's front facing the front-enders. Not if it's just buried in a function call, especially `protected` or `private` *(as in `internal`)*.

Comment: What _counts_ is 1) how readable and easily understandable it is, and 2) how fast it runs. Your first code with nested-ifs looks fine. Don't think you have to get fancy with objects and refactoring and whatnot, just because some compsci book says you have to do it.

Comment: @CodeAngry what happen when i want to support other state? the method become messier..

Comment: @slier That's why you need to paste more explicit code and explain what you want to achieve, what states, how many, where are they stored (dynamic or hard-coded)... We can't guess based on a snippet. From what I see, my comments stand.

Comment: @slier **That `code` is not complex.** I can show you complex code but if I do that, you'll probably end up in hospital if you find this intimidating.

Comment: @CodeAngry haha so that mean im not a bad coder :) thx for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try not to over-complicate this. In my opinion, the code is not complex enough to justify the use of object-oriented design patterns.

As I see it, your code basically boils down to validating an input with different regular expressions (which depend on some user-specified flags like `allow_num` and `allow_space`.

So my suggestion is the following (the basic refactoring is constructing part of the regular expression based on configuration before *using* this expression in any validation logic):

```
protected function isTextValid() {
    $allowedCharacters = 'A-Za-z';

    if ($this->data['allow_spaces']) {
        $allowedCharacters .= '\s';
    }
    if ($this->data['allow_num']) {
        $allowedCharacters .= '\d';
    }

    if (!preg_match("#^[{$allowedCharacters}]+\$#", $this->value)) {
        $this->messages = foo ? foor : bar;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i think u r right..i wat over-complicate it..nice suggestion u have there..never think about it

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer, then. :)